# Cplex giving the same solutions for all the variables

Tags: optimization, cplex

I am trying to maximize a problem that contains a set of continuous variables (x_1,...,x_n \in [0,1]) using CPLEX.
he problem is that culex always gives me all the variables x_1,.., xn =0.5 which is the wrong answer. I changed the c matrix (cost function), and do warm startup, but nothing changes the solutions. It gives always the solution of 0.5 for all variables.

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model()
x = [mdl.continuous_var(0,1,name="x%s" % i) for i in range(len(c))]

objective =  mdl.sum(
    [c[i, j] * x[i] * (1 - x[j]) for i in range(len(c)) for j in range(len(c))]
)
mdl.maximize(objective)
warmstart=mdl.new_solution()
warmstart.add_var_value(x[0],0.5)
warmstart.add_var_value(x[1],0.25)
mdl.add_mip_start(warmstart)

sol=mdl.solve(log_output=True)
```

I expect to get different solutions for different variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you derive x * x - x you get 2 * x - 1 so you get the max value when x is 0.5.

So what you get is normal.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, hope-that-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc.